# Counting permutations with a fixed number of descents and an extra condition

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

I am computing the volumes of certain polytopes and it turns out that knowing a "closed formula" for the following number would help a lot.

> Determine the number of permutations $\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_{n}$ such that $\sigma$ has exactly $k$ descents and such that in the segment $\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_s$ there are at most $t$ descents.

A clarification: a descent in a permutation $\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n$ is an index $i\in [n-1]$ such that $\sigma_i > \sigma_{i+1}$.

At first glance one can think of "choosing" the first $s$ numbers for $\sigma$ (inline notation) and counting in how many ways one can reorder them so that there are $0\leq j\leq t$ descents in that part, and then order the remaining $n-s$ numbers producing $k-j$ descents. Namely, do something like
$$ \sum_{j=0}^t \binom{n}{s} A_{s,j} A_{n-s,t-j},$$
where $A_{n,k} = \#\{\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n : \operatorname{des}(\sigma) = k\}$ is the classical Eulerian number.

This, however, does not work because we lose track of how the numbers $\sigma_s$ and $\sigma_{s+1}$ compare (that could introduce an extra descent).

By pretending a "closed formula" I intend a (possibly multiple) sum of products of binomial, Stirling and Eulerian numbers.

Comment: There is a way to count permutations which have given descent set in terms of inner products with ribbon Schur functions (see Stanley EC 2, Chapter 7), but this is probably not the kind of formula you are after.

Comment: (You can also write the number of permutations with descents in a given position as an inclusion-exclusion type alternating sum of multinomials, which amounts to the same thing as my previous comment.)

Comment: Thanks Sam. I will verify if a formula of that type does indeed simplify the work.